# Haskell: Converting between ByteStrings and different text encodings

Tags: text, haskell, encoding

I'd like to translate between Strings and ByteStrings using various encodings.

I know there is the utf8-string package which handles the UTF8 encoding. However, there are a lot of other encodings described in [System.IO](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO.html).

I also see the [Data.Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.0.6) package which can translate between String, Text and ByteString using different encodings.

What's the most appropriate way to translate between String and ByteString using the various encodings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The straightforward way: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding
- Via iconv bindings: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iconv-0.4.0.2
- Via icu bindings: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu